# Background Url dinâmico Css

Tags: php

Para alterar uma propriedade `html` dinamicamente pelo `php`, eu uso um código semelhante a esse :

```
<img src="<?php echo $foo;?>"/>
```

É possível alterar a Url do `background` no css pelo `php`

exemplo:

```
.foo{background:url('foo.jpg');}
```

Comment: Pode alterar via `style=`, inline, ou criar um `<style>`, ou criar um `x-background`, por exemplo, e manipular via JS. Acho que é a única opção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma página PHP para gerar CSS dinâmico de acordo com sua necessidade da seguinte forma:

1. Crie a página estilo.php
2. Coloque o `header` da mesma para css `header("Content-type:
   text/css")`

Exemplo:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css");
?>
.foo{
    <?php
        //condições aqui
    ?>
}
```

E em sua página você pode chamar o arquivo com o link igual a um css normal

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.php" />
```

Se quiser alterar o CSS de um elemento diretamente no HTML, você pode usar CSS inline com PHP, exemplo:

```
<div class="foo" style="background-image:<?php echo $foo; ?>;"></div>
```

Dessa forma mesmo que no documento CSS `foo` tenha algum `background-image`, o mesmo será desconsiderado e o inline será interpretado no lugar dele.

Você também pode alterar diretamente a tag `src` ou colocar um `style` no elemento que deseja manipular com JS, exemplo:

```
$('#seu-elemento').attr("src", "caminho-para-nova-imagem");
```

Ou manipular as propriedades `css` do mesmo

```
$('#seu-elemento').css({"background-image" : "caminho-para-nova-imagem"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Só se o seu CSS for gerado no arquivo (phtml) no arquivo .css ele não processa PHP não sendo possível fazer isso.

É possivel fazer via javascript.

Comment: é possível fazer com que o `css` interprete o `php`, ou melhor dizendo fazer do arquivo `php` um folha de estilo ?